# ZADD Redis error

Tags: python-3.x, redis

I am implementing a targeted search using Redis
Below the function for indexing ads

```
def index_ad(conn,id,locations,content,type,value):
    pipeline = conn.pipeline(True)

    for location in locations:
        pipeline.sadd('idx:req:'+location,id)

    words = tokenize(content)
    for word in words:
        pipeline.zadd('idx:'+word,id,0)

    rvalue = TO_ECPM[type](1000,AVERAGE_PER_1K.get(type,1),value)
    pipeline.hset('type:',id,type)
    pipeline.zadd('idx:ad:value:',id,rvalue)
    pipeline.zadd('ad:base_value:',id,value)
    pipeline.sadd('terms:'+id,*list(words))
    pipeline.execute()
```

I get the following error:
 Command # 3 (ZADD idx:look 0 1) of pipeline caused error: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

Comment: This error is triggered because the key you're trying to `ZADD` to already exists **and is not** a Sorted Set.